# Cost for Google Map API use in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, wms

I have android app which uses Map. I am using my own tile provide. I created a tileprovider class and have given url of my map server. Also have proper authentication key in adndroidmanifest.xml.

I want to know if i need to pay google for using the maps in my android application although I am using my own tile provider (auth key is form google).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611865/google-maps-does-it-cost-money

Answer (score 4):

No. You don't have to pay for Google Maps Android API v2 even if you don't use your own `TileProvider`.